# Как можно узнать какой день недели через php?

Tags: php

Как можно узнать какой день недели через php? Например публиковано `в 18.10.2015` то показывать `7` (воскресение).

```
<?php
echo timestamp('1445180844');
function timestamp($time) {
 // Фунуция
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo timestamp('1445180844');
function timestamp($time) {
    echo date("N", $time);
}
```

Описание функции `date()` со всеми вариантами можно посмотреть в [доках](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.date.php).