# Как определить наступление всех дней недели?

Tags: php

Как определить наступление всех дней недели? Нужно конкретно зафиксировать наступление и проверить. Зафиксировать автоматически, чтобы значение менялось каждый день и проверка проводилась с той же частотой.
Наступил первый день недели => вывести "понедельник" и т. д..

P.S. Нет необходимости мудрить циклы, сейчас куда уместнее будет if

Comment: Воспользуйтесь поиском -  [вопрос1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/460143/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-php), [вопрос2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35931/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (date("w")) {
    case 0:echo "Понедельник";break;
    case 1:echo "Вторник";break;
    ..
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Php день недели**

Стандартные дни недели по-английски.

Самое первое что приходит на ум это вывод самого простого – вывод английских дней недели, делается это так:

Полное наименование дня недели от Sunday до Saturday

```
echo date( "l" );
```

Пример:

```
Friday
```

**Php номер дня недели**

Это делается таким же образом как и в первом случае, только нужно изменить букву в функции

Это будет английская буква N

```
echo date( "N" );
```

Результат работы функции:

```
5
```

**Php день недели на русском**

Создадим массив

```
$days = array( 1 => "Понедельник" , "Вторник" , "Среда" , "Четверг" , "Пятница" , "Суббота" , "Воскресенье" );
```

Если мы выведем, например, так:

```
echo date( "N" );
```

То выдаст численное значение дня недели.

```
5
```

Ну и далее нам нужно обратиться к ячейке массива под нашим номером… вот так:

```
$days[date( "N" )];
```

Ну и результат:

```
Пятница
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, я неверно высказался.
Нужно зафиксировать автоматически, чтобы значение менялось каждый день и проверка проводилась с той же частотой.

Comment: значение будет изменяться автоматически после 00:00